# gdal_merge not recognized as internal or external command in OSGeo4W

Tags: gdal, osgeo

I've just installed OSGeo4W and am trying to run gdal_merge from the OSGeo4W Shell from a directory other than C.

```
gdal_merge.py -o output.tif -a_nodata 0 1.tif 2.tif
```

I also tried: `gdal_merge -o output.tif -a_nodata 0 1.tif 2.tif`

I receive the following error:

> gdal_merge is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I checked several directories in C:\OSGeo4W and I found gdal_merge.py is in C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python37\Scripts. Do I need to duplicate the .py folder somewhere else? Thanks for your help. I thought gdal_merge should be included in the list of shell commands.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue I also ran into. It is apparently caused by OSGeo4W installing two Python Environments and in this case it defaults to setting up the wrong one.

**You can fix the issue by first calling "py3_env"**.

This will set up the proper Python environment after which you can call gdal_merge.

Also see [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273870/osgeo4w-shell-with-python3) dealing with approximately the same issue

I hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:** gdal_merge.py: not found

**Solution**

```
apt install gdal-bin
```

Test it by simply typing `gdal_merge.py` on the terminal after installation and it'll show you how to use the utility.

Originally I posted my answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/449274/217765